# Clearing out canvas

Tags: processing

I'm trying to program an intro. I want the canvas to erase itself after it. I already have the trigger, but I do not know how to clear the canvas. Would just changing the background work? I still want to make stuff after it.
Here is the code:

```js
void setup () {
  frameRate(10);
  stroke(255, 255, 255);
  noFill();
  rect(100,155,300,300);
  size(500, 500);
} 
void square () {
    for (int x = 100; x <= 300; x += 100) {
        for (int y = 155; y <= 355; y += 100) {
            fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
            rect(x, y,100,100);
        }
    }
};
void draw () {
  int time = 0;
  int logoLength = 100;
  if (time < logoLength) {
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    background(0, 0, 0);
    textFont(createFont("Lucida console", 19));
    textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
    text("Ghost Cube Games presents",250,59);
    time++;
    print(time);
    square();
  } else if (time == logoLength) {
    background(255, 255, 255); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @cpburnz This question is tagged with [tag:processing], so the question is presumably about a Processing canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the [`background()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/background_.html) function.

`background(0);` draws a black background.

`background(255);` draws a white background.

`background(255, 0, 0);` draws a red background.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://www.processing.org/reference/background_.html).

For a more specific example, if you want to show an intro screen, you can simply keep track of whether the intro screen is showing in a `boolean` variable. If that variable is `true`, then draw the intro screen. If not, then draw whatever else you want to draw. If you do this from the `draw()` function, then you don't really have to worry about clearing the screen, since calling the `background()` function will do that for you:

```java
boolean showingIntro = true;

void draw() {

  background(0);

  if (showingIntro) {
    text("INTRO", 20, 20);
  } else {
    ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  showingIntro = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I just realized that the trigger doesn't wanna work. I was trying to place the frame rate at 10, and use `int time` and `time++` to check wether it has reach the time limit. but time does not update. I made sure `time++` is on `void draw`. What do I do?

Comment: @VictorQuintana It sounds like you're declaring your `time` variable inside the `draw()` function, but I can't be sure without seeing a [mcve]. Maybe post a new question? Also, Processing already has a variable that does that for you: [`frameCount`](https://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: My error was in declaring `time` on the `draw()` function. Since putting it on `setup()`makes it local, i thought I was out of options. I just declared the variable outside both functions. It was setting the variable to 0 each frame. Anyways, thanks for the incredible advice! It's just that I'm a noob.